# NSDate conversion setting weekday

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have an NSDate object `*myDate`.I can get the week day from this date and I want to set the weekday to an `integer c` and get the new date object in that week only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
            NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
            [formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyy"];
            date = [formatter dateFromString:string];

            NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
            NSInteger units = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit |       NSWeekdayCalendarUnit;
            NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:units fromDate:date];
            NSInteger day = [components day];
            NSInteger weekday = [components weekday]; // if necessary
```

Answer (score 2):

I searched for it and I found the answer,here is the code..

```
  NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
                [comps setDay:1];
             NSDate   *newDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];
                NSLog(@"new date==%@",newDate);
```

This will return date of the next day.